# How can I keep my doctype with htmlunit + the page.asXml method

Tags: seo, integration-testing, doctype, htmlunit, headless

When I run page.asXml() with HtmlUnit I lose my page's doctype.  Is there a work around?

Note: the intent is to serve up DOM for Google.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the code you are using, and to indicate exactly what you mean by losing the page's doctype.

Comment: Rodney, I felt better not complicating this one with code, as I am using IKVM to run HtmlUnit in .net.  My page loads 99.99% correctly the way we have it.  The only noticeable difference is the doctype exclusion, which when included renders the page exactly the same.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by "losing the doctype"... asXml() simply returns a String of the page's HTML.   Are you saying calling asXml() changes the page object?

Comment: yes, so I have an html 5 doctype of <!DOCTYPE html> on my page, the asXml drops it.  My temporary fix is: return page.asXml().Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", "<!DOCTYPE html>");

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
p.getWebResponse().getContentAsString()
```

instead of

```
p.asXml()
```

I just tried it against http://google.com, and in the former case "<!doctype html>" remained in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried your code, and I found that it doesn't return the executed/eval'd javascript, the way the asXml did with the wait for background javascripts methods did.  I checked the API and it says that it's the original web response, which isn't really what I want.  My solution, works for the time being :-\

Comment: +1: The "lost" doctype can re-obtained by parsing `getContentAsString()`.  Seems the OP didn't want to do this and instead wanted to hard code a new doctype of `<!DOCTYPE html>`.